# Grub rescue fixed, But again showing "error no such partition entering rescue mode" after reboot

Tags: grubrescue

Im using a dual boot system, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. I tried to resize windows primary partition and after rebooting, shows

```
error:no such partition entering rescue mode
```

I fixed it.

But after rebooting, again it shows as the same.

[image]

Comment: If the error shows again, what do you mean when you say you fixed it?

Comment: I found my grub file located at (hd0,msdos3), so I typed the following commands   :   set boot=(hd0,msdos3)     set prefix=(hd0,msdos3)/boot/grub     insmod normal      normal

Comment: If you can access Ubuntu, then run `sudo update-grub2` and let's see if at least you can get your grub back. But be aware that windows may not run again. Resizing partitions is always a risky thing.

Comment: Okay. Thanks...